# is it possible to keep data while browser is open

Tags: javascript

```
sessionStorage.setItem('img', $('#cpimgt').attr('src'));
```

this will keep data until tab is closed.

```
localStorage.setItem('img', $('#cpimgt').attr('src'));
```

this will keep data forever (if user doesn't clear them).

I need some storage keeping data while browser is open.
So if a tab is closed I need that data on another tab, but clear them automatically when browser is closed.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible in JS. Data is either destroyed on tab close or when cleared with session/local storage respectively, or after a certain length of time with cookies - In PHP though you can use sessions: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp   - these should allow you to save session data only until the browser is closed.

Comment: It is possible to keep the data while some parts of your application are open in some tabs. Will that satisfy you?

Comment: @zfrisch: Sessions are built on cookies; they don't allow anything more.

Comment: @NikitaIsaev, no, I need that data regardless some tabs are closed or not.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to differentiate between a tab closing or the browser closing.

Comment: @puerto this seems to be impossible. You can only choose either of:
- keeping the data forever
- keeping the data while the current tab is open
- keeping the data while there is at least one tab in your application open in the browser.

Comment: You could use a counter to keep the data while at least a single tab with your app is open, and destroy it when the last tab with your app is closed. But nothing more

Comment: @SLaks hm, my mistake. I find the official PHP documentation annoyingly difficult to navigate(honestly I don't know how anyone could think that it was palatable), but I did double-check there and you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49636/can-a-webpage-read-another-pages-cookies

> Yep this is defended against using the same origin policy, which
>   generally prevents one site reading anothers cookies.
>
> When you see behaviour where adverts seem to know where you've been
>   it's likely due to 3rd party ad tracking cookies.
>
> So as a simplified example if you go to site A which uses an ad
>   network, that ad network can record that you were on that site by
>   placing a tracking cookie on your PC.
>
> Then when you go to Site B which uses the same ad network, the ad
>   network reads the cookie that was set when you were on Site A (which
>   it can do 'cause it's loading content from it's domains in both cases
>   so it doesn't break same origin) and can then offer you adverts based
>   on your browsing habits.

Comment: I see. But yet it should be possible in the future, on some different platform.